# Setting visibility to ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have issues setting visibility to a specific ListViewItem.

```
 foreach (Oseba item in osebe_listView.Items)
                        {

                            if (o == item)
                            {
                                object ob = (object)osebe_listView.Items[count];
                                ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)ob;
                                lvi.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                                count++;
                            }
                        }
```

What I want is to find the ListView item that is equal to a object from type "Oseba" and set it's visibility to collapsed.

Comment: Please describe your problem. What is your issue? Does your code not compile? Is there a runtime error? Is the code not doing what you want to achieve?

Comment: This code compiles but doesnt work, because object is having a null value. I don't know how to get an object of type listviewitem, so I can set it to collapsed

Comment: To say it simple: I wish to find a specific ListViewItem that has same values as a object type Oseba(Oseba is populating the listView)

Comment: How is Oseba populating the ListView? Via the ItemsSource? Show how you populate the ListView. And you don't have to answer these questions as comments, just edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how the items are bound to your list box, so this is a shot into the dark, but i think you wan't something like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in osebe_listView.Items)
{
  if ((item.DataContext as Oseba) != null)
  {
      item.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  }
}
```

But maybe you should take a look at Filters. [WPF Filter a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358113/wpf-filter-a-listbox)

Comment: How does this match the two objects ??

Comment: I am populating items with this xaml syntax: DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding priimek}"  . In code-behind, I only use add and clear, though I could use a binding :/

Comment: What is your ItemSource? Just show your your View and ViewModel - or the code which fills your ListView

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem method to get a reference to the visual container for a data item provided that the container has actually been created:

```
foreach (var item in osebe_listView.Items)
{
    if (o == item)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = osebe_listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
        if(lvi != null)
            lvi.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        count++;
    }
}
```