# Filter Method of ICollectionView and Properly Binding and ObservableCollection in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm getting stuck into MVVM in WPF and I have setup an `ObservableCollection` and an `ICollectionView`. The `ICollectionView` is set as the ItemsSource of a `DataGrid`, and the model is a type of `Job`.

I've setup getters and setter for both of the collections however when I am setting a `Filter` on the `ICollectionView` instead of the `Job` being filtered by the `SearchString` they're just replicated over and over again, leading me to believe that they way I have the collections setup is totally wrong.

Here is how the two collections are get/set:

```
public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var job in _allJobsList)
            _allJobs.Add(job);
        return _allJobs;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_allJobs == value) return;
        OnPropertyChanged("AllJobs");
    }
}

public ICollectionView AllJobsView
{
    get
    {
        _allJobsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AllJobs);
        return _allJobsView;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_allJobsView == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _allJobsView = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AllJobsView");
    }
}
```

Now I have a stringcalled `SearchString` that is bound to a `TextBox.Text`. When the text changes I do the following:

```
public string SearchString
{
    get => _searchString;
    set
    {
        if (_searchString == value) return;
        _searchString = value;
        FilterJobs();
        OnPropertyChanged("SearchString");
    }
}

private void FilterJobs()
{
    AllJobsView.Filter = x =>
    {
        var viewJob = x as Job;
        return viewJob != null && viewJob.Number.Contains(_searchString);
    };
}
```

Now when the page first loads, there are the correct `Jobs` loaded into the `DataGrid`. However, as soon as the user types the `Jobs` are duplicated if the `Job.Number` does contain the `SearchString`. How am I able to setup the collections so that I can appropriately set a filter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438710/1069200

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the getter of your ObservableCollection. Every time you "get" the collection, you are adding every item to the collection all over again.

Your code:

```
get
{
    foreach (var job in _allJobsList)
        _allJobs.Add(job);
    return _allJobs;
}
```

Instead, it should be:

```
get
{        
    return _allJobs;
}
```

The setter of your ObservableCollection is also missing the "setter" (private field = value) code:

```
set
{
    if (value != _allJobs)
    {
        _allJobs = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AllJobs");
    }
}
```

---

Your Property AllJobs would then be:

```
private ObservableCollection<Job> _allJobs;
public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs
{
    get
    {        
        return _allJobs;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _allJobs)
        {
            _allJobs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AllJobs");
        }
    }
}
```

The initialization of your collection should be someplace else (and not in the getter of your property), like in the constructor of the ViewModel or/and in a method that a command calls after the user asks for a refresh of the collection.

For example, if your VieModel is called `MyViewModel` and your `List<Job>` is called _allJobsList, you can initialize your collection like so:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    //fill the _allJobsList first, getting from a database for example: _allJobsList = GetJobs();
    //and then create an observable collection from that list
    AllJobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>(_allJobsList);
}
```