# c# searching in textbox from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, search, listbox

I have an textbox and listbox with persons names. I want to type the name in the textbox and it should update the Listbox information. But I don't know how to do it. How should I do it?

I would like to filter the listbox rows when something is written in the textbox.

MainWindow.xaml code:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="127" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Name="PersonLstbox"
             Margin="10,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Textbox code:

```
<TextBox Name="searchpersonbx" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="420,150,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="searchpersonbx_TextChanged"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs code:

```
    private void searchpersonbx_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: what is the collection for the binding

Comment: What do you mean by `it should update the Listbox information`? How should it update the Listbox information?

Comment: The information on the listbox updates when I write something in the textbox.

Comment: Do you mean you want to *filter* your listbox rows based on your textbox' content?

Comment: Yes, you said that already. How **specifically** should the *information on the listbox update* when you *write something in the textbox*? Note we have asked for **specific** twice now. Repeating the same thing  over and over again in response isn't going to help you get an answer. Instead, [edit] your question and be more **specific** about what you're asking.

Comment: Did you see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358113/wpf-filter-a-listbox ? Might be related to you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify your code as below:-

Here I have used [`StartsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all the strings in specified order

your user name list

```
List<string> userName = new List<string>();
```

TextChanged Event

```
private void searchpersonbx_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   string text = searchpersonbx.Text;
   List<string> filteredUserName = userName.Select(x => x.StartsWith(text)).ToList();
   listBox.ItemsSource = filteredUserName;
}
```