# How to add a row with text box in WPF DataGrid to be used as search box

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want the first row of WPF DataGrid to be text boxes so that it can act as search box. Something similar to below :
[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358113/wpf-filter-a-listbox

Comment: Looks like i have to create a custom DataGrid. https://www.kailashsblogs.com/2020/06/wpf-custom-datagrid-in-c.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve using link :
http://wpf-tutorial-net.blogspot.com/2013/11/filter-datagrid-wpf-c-example.html

[image]